# Does this:$(\cos x) ^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}+(\sin x) ^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}=1$ have integers solution?

Tags: trigonometry, diophantine-equations

I want to know if this equation $(\cos x) ^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}+(\sin x) ^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}=1$ have integers solution , however [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(+(cosx)%5E(1%2Fcos+x)%2Bsinx+%5E(1%2Fsinx))+%3D1) assumed all it solutions are real , but probably there is any method to disproof or proof that is has solutions in integers ?

Comment: So do you have a closed form way of expressing the two solutions in $[0,\pi/2]$? Let $x_1, x_2$ Be these two solutions. Then all the solutions to the equation are of the form $x_1+2n \pi$ and $x_2+2n \pi$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Did you graph it for $x \in (0, \frac 12 \pi)$? The function is undefined at $x=0$ but the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from above is 1. There are two answers in the interval $x \in (0, \frac 12 \pi)$ and the chances are that you can get close to some large integer by adding the appropriate multiple of $2 \pi$ but never actually get an integer.

Comment: @stevengregory. Can you say your assumption explicitly? We are saying that one assumes that the solutions $x_1, x_2$ are transcendental and in fact one would guess that $x_i +2n\pi $ are never rational. What would be the way of expressing this algebraically? 

Something like $x_i \notin \mathbb{Q}[\pi]$?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know explicitly what the roots are, so I can't draw any actual conclusions.

Comment: My guess is that we cannot prove it, but I might be wrong.